# Input Boxes validation with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello this is my second attempt to solve this problem with JQuery
I need Check that a row of input must be minor than other one in the same row for a dinamic table of "n" rows, before send my form...I need check row by row using the input "ID" property...

Here my Code: http://jsfiddle.net/cespinoza/bQcu2/36/

```
    <form >
Line 1 Get <input type="val1" name="text1" id="desp" /> from <input type="val1" name="text1" id="cantidad" /><br>
Line 2 Get <input type="val2" name="text2" id="desp" /> from <input type="val2" name="text2" id="cantidad" /><br>
Line 3 Get <input type="val3" name="text3" id="desp" /> from <input type="val3" name="text3" id="cantidad" /><br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Edited: Added the Original JS code

```
$('#desp').change(function(){

    if($('#desp').val() == $('#cantidad').val())
    {
     alert("First value is greater than second, sorry")
    return False;
    }
    else
    {

    alert("All ok, push to database")
    return True,
    }

});
```

Thanks in Advance.
Christian.

Comment: You mean the values have to be smaller with every input like 10,8,3?

Comment: Using an ID selector will only get you the first element it finds - change to classes if you need multiple

Comment: I need that the first input box value will be minor that the second box on every row...

Comment: Doesn't matter what you're trying to do.  `id`'s still **must** be unique.

Comment: Why do you have those strange "type" attributes ("val1", "val2", "val3")? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please also make your question self-contained by including the jQuery code.  Otherwise, when the link goes dead the question is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Finally was able to solve this problem, thanks anyway...

This was the solution:

```
function validar(obj,i){
        var1=Number(obj.value);
        var2=Number(document.getElementById("saldo"+i).value);

        if (var1>var2) {        
            obj.focus();
            alert("No puede Retirar mas del saldo existente");

            }

}

Line 1 Get <input type="val1" name="text1" id="des1" onblur="validar(this,1);" /> from <input type="val1" name="text1"  value="10" id="saldo1"    /><br>
Line 2 Get <input type="val2" name="text2" id="des2" onblur="validar(this,2);" /> from <input type="val2" name="text2" id="saldo2" value="10" /><br>
Line 3 Get <input type="val3" name="text3" id="des3" onblur="validar(this,3);"/> from <input type="val3" name="text3" id="saldo3" value="10"/><br>
```

Comment: +1 on this clear and self-contained answer.  However, I'm giving a -1 on your question since you failed to do the same.  I'll remove my down-vote if you can please add your original JavaScript to the original question.

Comment: Added, sorry by the delay Sparky672

Comment: No problem... I took it back.

Answer (score -1):

```
    <form >
Line 1 Get <input type="val1" name="text1" id="desp1" /> from <input type="val1" name="text1" id="cantidad1" /><br>
Line 2 Get <input type="val2" name="text2" id="desp2" /> from <input type="val2" name="text2" id="cantidad2" /><br>
Line 3 Get <input type="val3" name="text3" id="desp2" /> from <input type="val3" name="text3" id="cantidad3" /><br>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
$('#desp').change(function(){
var j;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++){
    if($('#desp'+i).val() == $('#cantidad'+i).val())
    {
     alert("First value is greater than second at line"+i);
    return False;
    }
    else
    {
       j++
    }
}
if(n=j)
{
alert('all is well');
return false;
}

});
```

the n value you should get based on number of lines

Comment: Your solution cannot work. 1. Where is `$('#desp')` element now that the `id` names have been fixed? 2. Your first conditional seems to be backwards. If they are equal, your message says one is greater.  3.  There are better ways to handle the value of `n` or to do the loop- see `.each()`.